# Get the current index in sort function

Tags: javascript

What I need to know is a way to get the current `index` in the compare function of `sort` method in an `array`. Suppose this code:

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function (a, b) { 
  return a - b; 
  //i need the current index of `a` and `b` here 
});
```

In the anonymous function, I need the current index of `a` and `b` objects. How can I get it?

Comment: I don't think `compare` function have `index` parameter

Comment: You need the current index of what? All you get is the result sorted...

Comment: Can you please edit the question and provide an example of what that index looks like? It'd be clear in the case of e.g. `forEach()` but I can't figure out what index you expect in a sort callback function.

Comment: @Mr.Alien both `a` and `b`

Comment: Probably a sort function shouldn't take into account the current position of the elements...

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani When you use `.sort()` use the `typeof a` and see what happens, it will return a number so you cannot use `.index` and similar properties like that, try nesting arrays name inside the function and use `.indexOf()` to return the current position of the number...

Answer (score 10):

Make an array of objects with indices...

```
var arr = [1,5,2,3,8,13, 1];
var arr2 = arr.map(function(o, i) {return {idx: i, obj: o}; }).sort(function(a, b) {
    console.log('a.idx:', a.idx, 'b.idx:', b.idx);
    return a.obj - b.obj;
});

for(var i = 0, j = arr2.length; i < j; i++){
    console.log('i:', i, 'arr2[i].obj:', arr2[i].obj);
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k6xdqpb2/

Answer (score 2):

The index of `a` or `b`?

```
var indexOfA = points.indexOf(a);
```

This will give you the index that `a` *first* appears in the array.

Depending on what you are trying to do, another option may be to use a `map` for sorting as described in more details under the 'Sorting with map' heading [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). An example of this approach is given in [deostroll's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30167647/120497).

Comment: Other than the caveat that this doesn't take into account duplicates (I know the original example doesn't have any), I'm not even sure what use this information is. I mean, look at the output: http://jsfiddle.net/b0gxeL1h/ - Having said that, that's not the *answer's* fault, rather the question

Comment: Yeah, `indexOf` will only get the first match. I agree on your point about the questionable usefulness of this information. One should also bear in mind the following from the documentation: `The compareFunction can be invoked multiple times per element within the array`.

Comment: My array consists of `object`s not primitive types.

Comment: The same caveat applies. If you have the same object in your array more than once then `indexOf` will return the position of the first occurrence of that object in the array.

Comment: Even if your objects are unique, using `indexOf` will slow your sort way down, to O(n^2*log(n)) I think.